# What is the Pattern for adding Buttons and Drop Down menus for an Eclipse Plugin Perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin

What is the pattern for adding Buttons\Drop Down menus to the perspective in an Eclipse Plugin?

Obviously I can add them to a canvas using SWT.  But I feel I am missing a trick by not utilising the full Eclipse Workspace.

Can any Eclipse-Plugin developers tell me what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Adding them where? Inside your view / editor? On the view toolbar? In the main menu / toolbar? You need to be much more specific as the answer is different in each case.

Comment: That's what my question is.  Should I add them as buttons to a Canvas on the Perspective, or should I add them to existing menus or have a separate Perspective for buttons etc..  Can Perspectives be linked?

Comment: A perspective is an arrangement of views and editors and occupies the entire window. You can't have a 'canvas on a perspective' - it would have to be in a view or editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perspective can contain views, editor, extensions etc. You have to use either view or editor to add button, combos and other SWT controls. A perspective defines how your views, editor etc are arranged in eclipse workbench.

In the eclipse plugin a plugin.xml file is created. Inside that you can add extensions of perspective. e.g.

```
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="perspectives.MyPerspective"
            fixed="true"
            id="Perspective.myPerspective"
            name="MyPerspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
```

you can add views and editors from perspective extensions e.g.

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="Perspective.myPerspective">
            <view
                  id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer"
                  minimized="false"
                  moveable="false"
                  ratio="0.5"
                  relationship="left"
                  relative="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView"
                  visible="true">
            </view>
    </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
```

Views and editors can be added programmatically in perspective class.

Extend IPerspectiveFactory. Place your code inside createInitialLayout()
e.g.

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout){        
      layout.addStandaloneView(MyView.ID, false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f,layout.getEditorArea());

      // Multiple views and editors can be added here with its area and direction.
      //You can set them moveable false or closable false. If you want them fixed.
        }
```

Your view class would be like this :

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart 
{
   public static final String ID = "myproject.views.MyView";
    // ID is a normal string and could be anything

   @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
     // Here parent is your composite where u can add your SWT controls e.g.
      Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
   }
}
```

I think it is helpful to you, For Help, you can visit:

http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-plug-in-development-creat-a-perspective/

or

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html

Comment: Good stuff.  Any pointers or references on having multiple view sin a perspective?